# SQL: Can't create function returning table. "Table is not valid at this position, expecting: bit, bool, boolean, ...."

Tags: sql, function

I can't figure out what's wrong with this SQL function... in "returns table" it complains that "Table is not valid at this position, expecting: bit, bool, boolean, ....". Does anyone know?

```
create table department(
    dept_name varchar(20),
    n_prof int,
    budget numeric(10,2),
    primary key (dept_name)
);

create table instructor(
    ID char(5),
    name varchar(20),
    dept_name varchar(20),
    salary numeric(8,2),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department (dept_name)
    );

create function instructors (dept_name char(20))
     returns TABLE
     as
     return 
        select ID, name, dept_name, salary
        from instructor 
        where instructor.dept_name=dept_name;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @jg , please let me know if you still getting error , now before use the below solution you have to drop the existing table with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `error`, I guess you are using `MYSQL` database.

As per [documentation on user defined functions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function-udf.html)
you can only return values of type `{STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}`

```
CREATE [AGGREGATE] FUNCTION function_name RETURNS {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}
    SONAME shared_library_name
```

If you want to read a `select` resultset you have to define a `procedure` but not `function`.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProcedure //

CREATE PROCEDURE 
  myProcedure( dept_name char(20) )
BEGIN  
    select ID, name, dept_name, salary
    from instructor 
    where instructor.dept_name=dept_name;
   ;  
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

And you can call procedure like

```
call myProcedure( 'CSE' )
```

That returns implicit objects based on the statements used in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query.

USE **Your_Database**

```
create table dbo.department(
    dept_name varchar(20),
    n_prof int,
    budget numeric(10,2),
    primary key (dept_name)
);
GO
create table dbo.instructor(
    ID char(5),
    name varchar(20),
    dept_name varchar(20),
    salary numeric(8,2),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department (dept_name)
    );
GO
create function dbo.instructors (@dept_name char(20))
     returns TABLE
     as
     return 
        select ID, name, dept_name, salary
        from dbo.instructor 
        where instructor.dept_name=@dept_name;
```

You have used `dept_name` which is already existing in your table column so use `@dept_name` instead of that.
Please use GO statement to separate the each transaction otherwise you will get error.

> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Line 19 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the
>   first statement in a query batch. Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@dept_name".

Comment: Thank you for the reply! My problem was different though, it was a matter with the return type as Vignesh pointed out... Best regards!